# the same Name for HTML.CheckBox MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to put the same NAME tag for Html.CheckBox somehow .

How I can do it? Here is my code... Thank you!

```
foreach (var answer in @question.Answers)
{
@Html.CheckBox("answer_CheckBox_" + answer.ID.ToString(), false, new { Value = answer.ID });  
<label style="margin-left: 0.5em;">@answer.Title</label>
<br />                                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an incrementing value as part of the `name` argument to [the `CheckBox()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538490.aspx) (the first argument), so naturally they're going to be different names in the rendered HTML.

If you need them all to have the same `name` attribute value, use a static value:

```
@Html.CheckBox("answer_CheckBox", false, new { Value = answer.ID });
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
@Html.CheckBox("answer", false, new { name="answer", value = answer.ID });
```

Comment: "answer_CheckBox_" + answer.ID.ToString() must have been taking over the name. Updated. Try again.